# I want to open the WhatsApp and pass text to it just like the phone no

Tags: android

```
Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.Data._ID }, ContactsContract.Data.DATA1 + "=?",
new String[] { "91"+phno+"@s.whatsapp.net" }, null);
Intent i;
if (c.getCount()>=1) {
    c.moveToFirst();
    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/" +c.getString(0)));
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
    i.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
    i.createChooser(i, "Share with");
    c.close();
}
 else{
    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("smsto:"+phno));
    i.putExtra("sms_body", msg);
    i.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
}
startActivity(i);
```

I had already put `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` in the code but it does nothing. I am new to Android, so simple and self explanatory code will be helpful.

Comment: So maybe your c.getCount returns < 1 or it's null or who knows. It's better if you supply us with stactraces/logcat and more info. To just ask us to go through your code won't work.